# issue with KeyListener not working

Tags: java, keylistener, runnable

While I have have been coding for quite a while, I cannot seem to get past this issue I'm having (I'm almost positive its a small syntax error somewhere i cannot catch and not a logic error). I'm making a sound board, and am using the number pad on my keyboard. I have a KeyManager class:

```
public class KeyManager implements KeyListener{


private boolean[] keys;
private boolean nine, eight, seven, six, five, four, three, two, one; 

public KeyManager(){
    keys = new boolean [256];
}

public void update(){
    nine = keys[KeyEvent.VK_9];
    eight = keys[KeyEvent.VK_8];
    seven = keys[KeyEvent.VK_7];
    six = keys[KeyEvent.VK_6];
    five = keys[KeyEvent.VK_5];
    four = keys[KeyEvent.VK_4];
    three = keys[KeyEvent.VK_3];
    two = keys[KeyEvent.VK_2];
    one = keys[KeyEvent.VK_1];
}



public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
public boolean isNine() {
    return nine;
}

public boolean isEight() {
    return eight;
}

public boolean isSeven() {
    return seven;
}

public boolean isSix() {
    return six;
}

public boolean isFive() {
    return five;
}

public boolean isFour() {
    return four;
}

public boolean isThree() {
    return three;
}

public boolean isTwo() {
    return two;
}

public boolean isOne() {
    return one;
}
}
```

which is simple enough, and I'm using a Frame class that extends JFrame as the main UI display:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements Runnable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Pane pane;
private ArrayList<Circle> c;
private KeyManager keyManager;

public Frame(){
    keyManager = new KeyManager();
    this.addKeyListener(keyManager);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pane = new Pane();
    this.add(pane);
    c = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    c.add(new Circle(20, 140));
    c.add(new Circle(80, 140));
    c.add(new Circle(140, 140));
    c.add(new Circle(20, 80));
    c.add(new Circle(80, 80));
    c.add(new Circle(140, 80));
    c.add(new Circle(20, 20));
    c.add(new Circle(80, 20));
    c.add(new Circle(140, 20));
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void init(){
    pane.draw(c);
}

public void update(){
    pane.draw(c);
    keyManager.update();
    if(keyManager.isNine()){
        System.out.println("pressed");
        c.get(8).press();
    }
    else{
        c.get(8).release();
        System.out.println("unpressed");
    }
}


public void run() {

    init();

    int fps = 60;
    double timePerUpdate = 1000000000/fps;
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime= System.nanoTime();
    long timer = 0;
    int updates = 0;

    while(true){
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerUpdate;
        timer+= now - lastTime; 
        lastTime = now;

        if(delta >= 1){
            update();
            updates ++;
            delta--;
        }

        if(timer >= 1000000000){
            //System.out.println("Updates and Frames: "+ updates);
            updates = 0;
            timer = 0;
        }

    }
}


}
```

For some reason, when I press the "nine" on my keyboard, it does not print out pressed in the Frame.update() method, but will only print out "unpressed." I'm lost as to what's causing this issue. This is the first time i'm using a KeyManager class rather than having the Frame do all the lifting since it's good programming practice, but logically it should work unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you registered your key manager at all.
How does the JFrame know that it has a key listener?

Add this line of code at the very top of your Frame class `this.addKeyListener(new KeyManager());`

Like so:

```
public Frame(){
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyManager()); // New code
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
```

Edit: for future reference always check the javadoc, because in this case the answer is there for you:

> The listener object created from that class is then registered with a
>   component using the component's **addKeyListener** method.

Javadoc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html

And again `addKeyListener` is mentioned in the official tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Edit for comment:

Lets debug the issue by adding some code to your key pressed event. By doing this we can find several things.

1) Is the key event even being fired.

2) What is the key code and char that is pressed

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("The following key was pressed: "+e.getKeyChar());
    System.out.println("With the following key code: "+e.getKeyCode());
    System.out.println("Is that the expected output?");
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}
```

Do you get the correct output form our new debug code? Is the keycode correct, is the character correct? Do your other number keys work?

One thing to remember here is that the numberpad numbers have a different key code to the normal number keys. I strongly suggest you rework your code to use `e.getKeyChar()` or to include the numpad keycodes in your `update()` method and use IF statements when either the normal or the num pad key is pushed and set your boolean to true/false.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did't realize I deleted that line instead of changing it from addKeyListener(this) to this.addKeyListener(keyManager) (As i initially implemented keyListener in Frame), but that still didn't work. Same issue.

Comment: Ok, so now that the listener is working we need to debug a key press. See me edit above showing what you need to do.

Comment: I was using the keycode for 9 instead of the number pad, and that is the issue. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Don't forget to make the answer as correct using the tick in the top left corner

Comment: Sorry, thought I clicked it :)